# Ipa file exported with "save for development deployment" option will expire after 2 or 3 months?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, apple-developer

My client complaining that after 2 or 3 months the app when launched opens and closes immediately and then they have to reinstall the app, my question is does the ipa file have some validity/expiry date once installed?

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453102/retrieve-certificate-expiration-date-from-an-ipa-file

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3fojzf/how_to_get_an_ipa_files_expiry_date_from_the/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks, i don't want to know how to check the expiry date, i want to know the period for which the ipa file exported with "Save for development deployment" will be valid, because my client can install the same ipa file again it works for another 2-3 months.

Comment: i think the validy is max 1 month, but i am not sure

Comment: Ok Thanks, if anybody know the actual time period please answer.

Comment: @ArivenNadar check url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453102/retrieve-certificate-expiration-date-from-an-ipa-file . If you are making only iPa not diawi link than it will depends on your expiration certificates.

Comment: As per Apple doc, "The app successfully launches if the app’s bundle ID matches the App ID, the signature matches the distribution certificate, and the device is in the device list of the ad hoc provisioning profile." Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html.  so your expectation of time duration is actually depends on certificate and provisioning profile validity period.

Comment: Is it possible the application is crashing? I think you can look at crash logs in Settings.app -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data.

Answer (score -1):

you need to make new Diawi url And send to client after adding his Device Udid in [Apple developer program](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1)
Drag and drop .ipa in Diwai with
https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: question is not to make new diwali. Question is How longer time valid iPa build.